# Reinstall virtualenv with tox when requirements.txt or setup.py changes

Tags: python, makefile, virtualenv, tox

Previously I was manually using a Makefile that looked something like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all: tests

.PHONY: tests
tests: py_env
    bash -c 'source py_env/bin/activate && py.test tests'

py_env: requirements_dev.txt setup.py
    rm -rf py_env
    virtualenv py_env
    bash -c 'source py_env/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements_dev.txt'
```

This had the nice side-effect that if I changed requirements_dev.txt or setup.py, it would rebuild my virtualenv.  But feels a bit clunky.

I'd like to use `tox` to do a similar thing.  I understand `tox` has a `--recreate` option, but I'd rather call that *only* when I need to.

My new setup is something like this:

```
# Makefile
.PHONY: all
all: tests

.PHONY: tests
tests:
    tox
```

and

```
# tox.ini
[tox]
project = my_project
envlist = py26,py27

[testenv]
install_command = pip install --use-wheel {opts} {packages}
deps = -rrequirements_dev.txt
commands =
    py.test {posargs:tests}
```

An ideal solution would use just things in `tox`, however an acceptable solution would involve the Makefile and the `--recreate` flag.

Comment: I want this answer as well.

Comment: a very creative way of using `make`, great idea.  writing this comment just to point out that for shell scripting it's much easier to use the commands in the `venv` directly: `py_env/bin/pip ...` instead of  `bash -c 'source py_env/bin/activate && pip ...`

Comment: what about tox-battery that tracks changes in requirements? https://pypi.org/project/tox-battery/

Comment: it doesn't generically solve the problem

Answer (score 14):

There seems to be an open issue in tox for just this problem.

https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/149 (click and add your comment and vote, making the authors aware about how common the issue is)

We'll need to either submit a patch or work around it. Workaround that come to mind:

1. List dependencies directly in the `tox.ini`. Use your build system to ensure that the tox.ini stays in sync with the `requirements.txt`.
2. Add a rule to your Makefile that does a tox --recreate whenever the requirements.txt changes.

Workaround 2 seems most straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the Makefile workaround I ended up going with:

```
REBUILD_FLAG =

.PHONY: all
all: tests

.PHONY: tests
tests: .venv.touch
    tox $(REBUILD_FLAG)

.venv.touch: setup.py requirements.txt requirements_dev.txt
    $(eval REBUILD_FLAG := --recreate)
    touch .venv.touch
```

Example:

```
$ make tests
touch .venv.touch
tox --recreate
[[ SNIP ]]
$ make tests
tox 
[[ SNIP ]]
$ touch requirements.txt
$ make tests
touch .venv.touch
tox --recreate
[[ SNIP ]]
```